# Mysql data load disabled/restrictions

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, loaddata

I am facing an issue in loading the data to MySQL.

Initially, I was using import wizard but sometimes it loads 0 records idk why. and sometimes it took 4 hours and still it could not load the data.

So I tried loading the data using a local path. But it kept on giving me errors - 2068, 3948.

I checked and added local_infile=ON in my ini.txt file in both client and server sections. but it did not work out.

Kindly help please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.